# is this sentence Grammatically right?

Tags: grammaticality

"Afterwards we can also discuss about the opportunities that we can explore together." is this sentence Grammatically right? should i use "discuss" & "about" both together?

Comment: Hi Ovi, welcome to EL&U. Unfortunately we don't do proofreading here. If you would like someone to answer your question, you need to explain what  aspect of the sentence you are worried about. i.e. why do you think that the sentence might be wrong?

Comment: [The answer to your question though is that you cannot use the preposition *about* with the verb *discuss*. This verb takes a direct object without any prepositions. So you need "discuss the opportunities" not "*discuss about the opportunities".]

Comment: Thank you Araucaria Man for your kind consideration. i understand, Actually i am a new member in this community and also a new user of English. So i expect support from you guys.....

Comment: Kind of you to provide the 'tip' on where his sentence has gone into grammatical error. By the way (considering the many times our members have said they don't do proofreading here) I should like to suggest that the technically correct meaning of proofreading is the revision of proofs to correct typographic errors (and not grammatical errors, which is surely what the members are referring to here!) -- I understand that you don't approve of spoonfeeding English language learners by correcting their blind errors, and I agree. But the term 'proofreading' is being used inaccurately in these pages!

Comment: Dear new English learner OVI -- It takes years to learn any language, but you are on the right track! There are 1200 languages that I don't know and only 3 and a 1/2 that I do -- just try to understand what the grammatical error was, when somebody provides a correction, and READ A LOT to become familiar with the usages! I am sure you will be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since **discuss** [is a transitive verb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discuss), you could just say

> we can also discuss the opportunities...

"the opportunities" are the object of the phrase, "We" is the subject, so there is no need to say "about."  If you were using an intransitive verb like "talk," then following it with a prepositional phrase would make sense:

> We can also **talk about** the opportunities...